# How to use Angular components from different folder?

Tags: html, angular, frontend

Seems like an obvious design decision for me but i can't seem to find any info on how to implement it.

I did the following:

1. created `/pages` folder and turned components in to modules for routing
2. created `/components` folder for components only

**src/app/components/footer/footer.component.ts :**

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-footer',
  templateUrl: './footer.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./footer.component.css']
})

export class FooterComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
}
```

**src/app/pages/home/home.component.ts :**

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { TranslateConfigService } from 'src/app/services/translate-config.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private translateConfigService: TranslateConfigService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeRoutes } from './home.routes';
import { TranslateModule } from '@ngx-translate/core';

import { HomeComponent } from './home.component';
import { FooterComponent } from 'src/app/components/footer/footer.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    HomeComponent,
    FooterComponent,
  ],
  exports: [HomeComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(HomeRoutes),
    TranslateModule

  ]
})
export class HomeModule { }
```

I didn't import anything explicitly, but when i try to use  from `/components` in some page's html - i get an error saying

```js
Error: src/app/pages/terms/terms.component.html:391:1 - error NG8001: 'app-footer' is not a known element:
1. If 'app-footer' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'app-footer' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
```

Comment: Have you imported your HomeModule in whichever module is consuming the components? AppModule perhaps?

Comment: You need to export `FooterComponent` also in order to use outside `HomeModule`.

Comment: Have you added ```FooterComponent``` to module's declaration (in whichever module you are using it) ?

Comment: @WillAlexander 
I did `export class FooterComponent implements OnInit {..}` in footer.component.ts

Comment: @PawanSharma

I'm using my footer component in home.compoonent so in `home.moudle.ts` i did: 
1) ` import { FooterComponent } from 'src/app/components/footer/footer.component';`
2) @NgModule({  imports: [ FooterComponent] });

Still does not work

Comment: add `exports: [HomeComponent, FooterComponent]` in HomeModule

Comment: @navnath seems to work now. I have another page module in `/pages` dir called `terms`. What do i have to import to terms.module.ts to make `footer` component available there?

Comment: Just add `HomeModule` in imports array  like `imports: [HomeModule]` in `TermsModule` , then `FooterComponent` will be available in `TermsModule`

Comment: @navnath Thanks for dedicating your time for a noobie like myself) You helped a lot. Maybe i'll update the question to make it a bit more usefull for the community